# JavaScript method is not calling from backend

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

In my page I have a login control:

```
<asp:Login ID="EMSLogin" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="EMSLogin_Authenticate">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="wrapper">
            <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" CssClass="holder">
                <asp:Panel ID="Panel3" runat="server" CssClass="loginBox one_edge_shadow">
                    <h1>
                        Login Credentials</h1>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel4" runat="server" CssClass="name topmargin">
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel5" runat="server" CssClass="label">
                            <asp:Label ID="UserNameLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User Name:</asp:Label>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel6" runat="server" CssClass="textBox">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" Height="16px" Width="165px" Font-Size="14px"
                                Font-Names="Arial Sans-Serif" ToolTip="Enter your valid login name" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="UserNameRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
                                ValidationGroup="EMSLogin">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <br class="clearfix" />
                    </asp:Panel>
                    <asp:Panel ID="Panel7" runat="server" CssClass="name topmargin">
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel8" runat="server" CssClass="label">
                            <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Password">Password:</asp:Label>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel9" runat="server" CssClass="textBox">
                            <telerik:RadTextBox ID="Password" runat="server" TextMode="Password" Height="16px"
                                Width="165px" Font-Size="14px" Font-Names="Arial Sans-Serif" ToolTip="Enter your valid password" />
                            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="PasswordRequired" runat="server" ControlToValidate="Password"
                                ValidationGroup="EMSLogin">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </asp:Panel>
                        <br class="clearfix" />
                        <telerik:RadButton ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In"
                            CssClass="loginButton" Font-Size="14px" Width="100px" ValidationGroup="EMSLogin"
                            ToolTip="Click to log in" />
                    </asp:Panel>
                </asp:Panel>
            </asp:Panel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

I have added the ScriptManager control to the page.

Now the `EMSLogin_Authenticate` is:

```
protected void EMSLogin_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) {
    RadTextBox UserName = EMSLogin.FindControl("UserName") as RadTextBox;
    RadTextBox Password = EMSLogin.FindControl("Password") as RadTextBox;

    if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text)) {
       FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, false);
    } else {
       Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(ScriptManager), "CallShowDialog", "showDialog();", true);     
    }
}
```

The JavaScript method `showDialog();` is defined in the page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDialog() {
        $(".jym").dialog("open");
        return false;
    }   
</script>
```

But it is not calling. There is nothing wrong with `showDialog()` since I have called it on the onclick method of an anchor tag; it is showing the dialog. If I write `alert()` in place of `showDialog()` in code behind then I can see the alert message.

What I am doing wrong? Is it not possible to call JavaScript in this way?

---

This is also not working:

```
System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, typeof(RadButton), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), "showDialog();", true);
```

Comment: Are you using jQuery ? I think jQuery may not have been initialized by the time you called ShowDialog. Replace the statement $(".jym").dialog("open"); with alert, if that works, then replace alert with $(document).ready(function(){$(".jym").dialog("open");}); and see if that works.

Comment: @KalyanGanjam Thanks for reply function showDialog() {
            alert('jym');
            return false;
        } worked but function showDialog() {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(".jym").dialog("open"); 
            });
            return false;
        } doesn't.

Comment: Shadow Wizard's answer below explained the approach I suggested with greater clarity. Follow Shadow Wizard's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RegisterClientScriptBlock` put the code before the document, so by the time you are calling the function, there is no element with class `jym` just yet. You can add `alert($(".jym").length)` to confirm that, you'll see 0.

Why not calling the function from client side?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    showDialog();
});
```

If you need it server side, just change your code to:

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(UserName.Text, Password.Text)) {
   FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserName.Text, false);
} else {
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(ScriptManager), "CallShowDialog", "$(document).ready(function() { showDialog(); });", true);     
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes `alert($(".jym").length)` is giving 0. But I don't understand your client side suggestion. Actually what I am willing to do is if the authentication failed then I want to show a dialog window.

Comment: I understand your confusion.. see my edit, it should be clear now.

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working: `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(ScriptManager), "CallShowDialog", "$(document).ready(function() { showDialog(); });", true);`. If I change the `showDialog()` as `function showDialog() {$(document).ready(function () {$(".jym").dialog("open");});}` and it's calling : `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(ScriptManager), "CallShowDialog", "showDialog();", true);` then it works. But after the error dialog has been shown if I refresh the page by browser's refresh button or press F5 the dialog again arrives.

Answer (score 0):

A few questions:

1. Is showDialog declared in the page header?
2. Is that function sitting in the proper script tag:
3. Try reforming your RegisterClientScriptBlock command:

   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "CallShowDialog", "showDialog();");

I don't think you need the overload for added the script tags.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes it is declared in head in <script/>. If I change the `RegisterClientScriptBlock` as you have shown the the showDialog(); text is visible on the page after postback.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the RadAjaxManager you have to use this:

```
RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(Page).ResponseScripts.Add("showDialog();");
```